The definition of the period domain
I am reading Voisin's Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry volume 1. On page 247 there is a concept called "flag space". I think the definition should be as follows: given a complex vector space $W$ and a decreasing sequence of positive integers less than $\dim W$, denoted by $b^1, \cdots, b^k$, set the flag manifold to be
$$ F_{b^.}W := \{ (K^1 , \cdots , K^k) \in \prod_{1 \leq p \leq k } \text{Grass}(b^p,W) \ | \ K^p \text{ is a decreasing filtration of } W \}. $$
Here Voisin states that it is clear to see that it is a complex submanifold of $ \prod_{1 \leq p \leq k } \text{Grass}(b^p,W) $ but I don't know why. How to show this?

It is enough to prove it for k=2, do you see it there?

@CraniumClamp Yeah I noticed that. But it is still hard for me to show the proposition in this simple case. Can you give me some hints?
